# Google Analytics App Script Get All media eventLabels That Contain a Specific Word

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am in the process of try to write a script that contain all the eventCategories that are related to just media and I want the evenLabels to only include the media title that have the word Headspace in the title.  I have a script but my results are completely wrong and I am not sure what I should change to correct it.

The script is:

```
function runDemo() {
  try {

    var firstProfile = getFirstProfile();
    var results = getReportDataForProfile(firstProfile);
    outputToSpreadsheet(results);

  } catch(error) {
    Browser.msgBox(error.message);
  }
}

function getFirstProfile() {
  var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
  if (accounts.getItems()) {
    var firstAccountId = accounts.getItems()[0].getId();

    var webProperties = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(firstAccountId);
    if (webProperties.getItems()) {

      var firstWebPropertyId = webProperties.getItems()[0].getId();
      var profiles = Analytics.Management.Profiles.list(firstAccountId, firstWebPropertyId);

      if (profiles.getItems()) {
        var firstProfile = profiles.getItems()[0];
        return firstProfile;

      } else {
        throw new Error('No views (profiles) found.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('No webproperties found.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('No accounts found.');
  }
}

function getReportDataForProfile(firstProfile) {

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(14);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel' ,             // Comma separated list of dimensions
    'filters': 'ga:eventLabel=~headspace',   // Display only google traffic                

  };


  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
     'ga:totalEvents', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}

function getLastNdays(nDaysAgo) {
  var today = new Date();
  var before = new Date();
  before.setDate(today.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
  return Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  // Print the headers.
  var headerNames = [];
  for (var i = 0, header; header = results.getColumnHeaders()[i]; ++i) {
    headerNames.push(header.getName());
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, headerNames.length)
      .setValues([headerNames]);

  // Print the rows of data.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, results.getRows().length, headerNames.length)
      .setValues(results.getRows());
}
```

Comment: define Completely wrong.     It would probably be easer to use account summaries report instead of what you are dong now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Google Analytics add-on in Google Sheets.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics/fefimfimnhjjkomigakinmjileehfopp?hl=en

This will allow you to access all you Google Analytics data without writing code. Then, if you need to manipulate the data further, you can move back to Google Apps Script.

Comment: I have already used the Google Analytics add-on but I need the script.  Is there a way to convert the Google Anacytics data automatically to script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by converting the data to script. Can you elaborate? I use the add-on to organize my data into various sheets and then I use GAS to output the manipulated data to new sheets.

Comment: I meant converting the report, where I have added the dimensions and filters, to script.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean. Are you talking about a report that you made in the Google Analytics interface? And what do you want your script to do that the plugin can't?